# Как добавить компонент в другой компонент при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть три компонента: OwnMessage, MessageInput, MessageList. В компоненте MessageList должны отображатся компоненты Message (сообщение какого-то пользователя) и OwnMessage (Сообщение, которое отправил я). В MessageInput я ввожу сообщение и нажимаю кнопку Send, после нажатия кнопки Send, компонент OwnMessage должен добавлятся в компонент MessageList, что-то типо appendChild. Вместо этого OwnMessage рендерится в компоненте messageInput, как мне передать OwnMessage после нажатия кнопки Send в MessageInput в MessageList? Я тупо не понимаю как их связать.

OwnMessage

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/OwnMessage.css';

class OwnMessage extends React.Component {
    editMessage = (e) => {
        const msgContainer = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.message-text');
        const savebtn = document.querySelector('.save-hide');
        const inputblock = document.querySelector('.message-input-text');
        inputblock.value = this.props.message;
        savebtn.style = 'display: inline';

        savebtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            const inputmsg = document.querySelector('.message-input-text');
            savebtn.style = 'display: none';
            msgContainer.textContent = inputmsg.value;
            inputmsg.value = '';
        })
    }
    deleteMessage = (e) => {
        e.target.parentNode.remove();

    }
    
    render() {
        const time = new Date();
        let hours = time.getHours();
        let minutes = time.getMinutes();
        const msgTime = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
            return(
                <div className="own-message">
                    <p className="message-text">{this.props.message}</p>
                    <button onClick={this.editMessage} className="message-edit">Edit</button>
                    <button onClick={this.deleteMessage} className="message-delete">x</button>
                    <time className="message-time">{msgTime}</time>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default OwnMessage;
```

MessageInput

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/MessageInput.css';
import OwnMessage from './OwnMessage';

class MessageInput extends React.Component {
    state = {
        users: []
     }
    sendMessage = () => { 
        const inputText = document.querySelector('.message-input-text');

        this.setState({
            users: [...this.state.users, <OwnMessage message={inputText.value} />]
          })
        inputText.value = '';
    }
    render() {

        return(
            <div className="message-input">
                <input type="text" className="message-input-text" placeholder="Message"></input>
                <button onClick={this.sendMessage} className="message-input-button">Send</button>
                <button className="message-input-button save-hide">Save</button>
                {this.state.users}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MessageInput;
```

MessageList

```
import React from 'react';
import Message from './Message';
import './styles/MessageList.css'

class MessageList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        show: true,
        counter: 1
    }


    render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        const counter = this.state.counter;
        return(
            <div className="message-list">

                <Message name = {data[0].user} msg = {data[0].text} photo = {data[0].avatar}/>
            <div className="messages-divider"></div>
                {this.state.show ? (
                    <Message name = {data[counter].user} msg = {data[counter].text} photo = {data[counter].avatar}/>
                ) : null
                }   

            </div>
            
        )
    }
}

export default MessageList;
```

Answer (score 0):

компонент OwnMessage должен добавлятся в компонент MessageList, вообще есть несколько вариантов (Portal(наверное самый правельный вариант), сохранить в родительском компоненте или redux и брать от тудо, да и тот же append почему бы и нет(да типо так нельзя но как по мне можно если совсем туго:))), но тут дело в другом...
в реале если я суть понял после кнопки send данные должны уйти на сервак, а в твоей компоненте MessageList данные должны приходить с того же сервака которые ты и должен в showList отрисовать

но в любом случее не компонент OwnMessage должен добавляться в MessageList а данные из OwnMessage

Comment: Сервера нету. Но уже разобрался как сделать правильно, спасибо)

Comment: рад был помочь)